# WPF multiline button disabling

Tags: c#, wpf, button, multiline

I have a button with multiline-text:

```
<Button x:Name="Start" IsEnabled="False">
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Some Text</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

If `IsEnabled` is `False`, then the button is disabled but the text inside the button is still black.

How can I set the `button-text` to a "disabled-style" - color?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that if you wrap your TextBlock in a Label, it will honor the IsEnabled style changes:

```
<Button x:Name="Start" IsEnabled="False">
    <Label>
        <Label.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yeah, but then you can't have alt+letter codes on your button. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a DataTrigger, that if the button is disabled, change the foreground of the TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock.Style>
<Style TargetType=TextBlock>
...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="..." />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```